# CSS issues none sense

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to perfect my jQuery menu.

However I run on some CSS issues and I'm stuck. Here's my issues.

```
#nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#nav li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav li ul {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
}

#nav li a {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 2;
  text-decoration: none
}

#nav li a:hover {
  color: #c0392b;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}



#nav ul li { 
    background-color: #e74c3c; 
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    list-style: disc;
}

#nav li:first-child { 
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

#nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}



#nav .fa { margin: 0px 17px 0px 0px; }

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#logo{
color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: normal;
}

.sidebar-icon {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  color: #fff;
}

.disp {
  opacity: 1!important;
  height:auto!important;
   transition: height 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}
```

I run on some CSS issues and I'm stuck. Here's my issues. 
I run on some CSS issues and I'm stuck. Here's my issues.

Comment: For the links, simply wrap all link contents into `<span>` (where they are missing in some of links) and then add `:first-child` rule: https://jsfiddle.net/pjb7jzjk/35/

Comment: And how about the #2 question the double border? and #3 question the scrollbars? How can I remove or fix those?

Comment: Don't use "min-width" for container DIVs in CSS: That's why the scrollbars appear.

Comment: And how about the #2 question the double border under each submenu? where are I can fix those?

Comment: Just display borders for all items except last ones. Smth like this: `nav li:not(:last-child) { border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa; }`

Comment: another way is (border-bottom-width: 0px;) https://jsfiddle.net/y8dgoyh8/ -- check on -- About

Comment: Add a class submenu to the sub menu and include style for it. https://jsfiddle.net/pjb7jzjk/37/

Answer (score 1):

To sum it up:

1. To add paddings to links without icons, wrap all text inside items into `<span>` (only those that have no `<span>` yet) and add `padding-left` to spans that have no icon before them:

   ```
   nav li span:first-child {
       padding-left: 24px;
   }
   ```
2. Display borders only for items that are last in the group:

   ```
   nav li:not(:last-child) {
       border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
   }
   ```
3. The scrollbar appears because you have `min-width` rule specified. Do not do it. It will mess up small screens because it will never collapse. Also remove `padding-right: 65px;` and `padding-right: 280px;` - they are bogus.

Here's the final fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pjb7jzjk/36/

P. S. I suggest you to add `overflow-y: scroll` rule to `.sidebar-nav` to make it scrollable on screens with small height.

Answer (score 0):

Ad.1 -  try to add

```
#nav li > ul > li {
padding-left: 3em;
}
```